# Copy selected key from a PowerShell array that can be splatted

Tags: powershell

I would like to copy selected properties from one PowerShell hash to another, then be able to 'splat' the hashtable that contains the selected properties:

```
function Test-Splat {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [string]$FirstName,
        [string]$LastName,
        [datetime]$BirthDate
    )
    
    Write-Host "FirstName: $FirstName"
    Write-Host "LastName: $LastName"
    Write-Host "BirthDate: $BirthDate"
}

# source hashtable
$Person = @{
    FirstName = 'First'
    LastName = 'Last'
    Gender = 'Male'
    BirthDate = '6/1/2020'
}

# copy selected properties (creates a Selected.System.Collections.Hashtable)
$Test = $Person | Select-Object FirstName, LastName, BirthDate

# splatting doesn't work as expected    
Test-Splat @Test
FirstName: @{FirstName=First; LastName=Last; BirthDate=6/1/2020}
LastName: 
BirthDate: 

# clone the original hashtable, then remove undesirable properties
$Test2 = $Person.Clone()
$Test2.Remove('Gender')

# splatting works correctly
Test-Splat @Test2
FirstName: First
LastName: Last
BirthDate: 06/01/2020 00:00:00
```

The second approach works, but if I have a large, initial hash table, calling`Remove()` repeatedly seems less than ideal.

Is there a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option fails because `Select-Object` will create a PsObject in  variable $Test; not a Hashtable.

You could use a loop to copy only the wanted properties from the first hash into a new one if that saves you repeated `Remove()` actions.

Something like

```
$newhash = @{}
'FirstName', 'LastName', 'BirthDate'  | Foreach-Object {
    $newhash[$_] = $Person[$_]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new hashtable and copy the relevant entries:

```
$paramNames = 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'BirthDate'
$splatTable = @{}

$Person.GetEnumerator() |Where-Object { $_.Name -in $paramNames } |ForEach-Object { $splatTable[$_.Name] = $_.Value }

Test-Splat @splatTable
```

I prefer doing it this way because I'm forced to opt-in, by name, for each parameter - so if someone adds new keys to `$Person` in the future we won't be passing random garbage to the target command

Answer (score 0):

After I adjusted my function to support the pipeline:

```
function Test-Splat {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]$FirstName,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]$LastName,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [datetime]$BirthDate
    )
    
    begin {Write-Debug 'begin'}
    process {
        Write-Debug 'process'
        Write-Host "FirstName: $FirstName"
        Write-Host "LastName: $LastName"
        Write-Host "BirthDate: $BirthDate"    
    }
    end {Write-Debug 'end'}
}
```

I made a variation of @Theo's syntax:

```
'FirstName', 'LastName', 'BirthDate'  | Foreach-Object -begin { $h = @{} } -process {
    $h[$_] = $Person[$_]
} -end { [pscustomobject]$h } | Test-Splat
```